# Location returns 0.0 with WIFI/3G/4G in Lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: android, gps, location, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to fetch location based on `WiFi/3G/4G` connection but it always returns `0.0` as `latitude and longitude`. If same code is used with `GPS ON` then it works so something is changed from 4.4 onwards.

Also tried following link but its not working too.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "GPSTracker";

private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
double speed;
double altitude;
double bearings;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 5000; // 10 seconds

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {

    try {

        if (mContext == null)
            Log.d("GPS Tracker", "Context is null");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled

            Log.d("GPSTracker", "No Provider is Enabled");

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                Log.d("GPSTracker", "Network Enabled");

                if (locationManager != null) {

                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        altitude = location.getAltitude();
                        speed = location.getSpeed();
                        bearings = location.getBearing();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {

                if (location == null) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("GPSTracker", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            altitude = location.getAltitude();
                            speed = location.getSpeed();
                            bearings = location.getBearing();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Is there any solution to get location based on `WiFi/Data`connection from `4.4 kitkat` onwards??

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the relevant code please

Comment: @DavidWasser code added

Comment: please try more efficient way of getting location like Fused Location API - http://mobilewebwizard.in/2015/03/fused-location-api-android-example/

Comment: @Vipinhelloindia It's not working too. Check `Android hive` example and it has the use of the same api

Comment: I will try ,you may like to report bug to Google if so .

Answer (score 6):

> The steps to be followed :

Step 1 : check the  following permission in Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> Step 2 : check the service class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;


public class  GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

public static boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
public static boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
static boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 2; // 2 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("onCreate", "Success !");
        latitudeAndLongtitude();
}

public void latitudeAndLongtitude()
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No provider found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        GPSTracker.canGetLocation = true;
        if(isGPSEnabled)
        {
            if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            Log.d("Network", "GPS");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                Log.d("locationManager", "is not null ");
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.d("Network", "GPS lat and long gets ");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isNetworkEnabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Helper.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), NameConversion.LATITUDE,String.valueOf(latitude));
                    Helper.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), NameConversion.LONGITUDE,String.valueOf(longitude));
                }else{
                    Log.d("location", "is getting null ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
        else if(isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isGPSEnabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Helper.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), NameConversion.LATITUDE,String.valueOf(latitude));
                    Helper.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), NameConversion.LONGITUDE,String.valueOf(longitude));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}
/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}
/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

public void sendLocationToServer() {
    Log.i("sendLocationToServer", "Called!");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("onDestroy", "Called!");
    stopSelf();

}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
 * lauch Settings Options
 * */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitudeAndLongtitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}}
```

> step 3 : Enable the service in Manifest file
>
> inside application tag

```
  <service
        android:name=“.your package name.GPSTracker"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

> setp 4 : start the service in where you want
>
> Hope this will work if you face stil problem may be your mobile will not get the GPS and Network Locaiton .

Comment: you are first checking network enabled. then again its checking GPS enabled. if it takes network value you dont get the correct latitude and longtitude . you code will check both option mine will not take both its first prefer only GPS

Comment: You service has dont have the onCreate method??? when you start the service from where it will excute???

Comment: I never had issue with service. Whenever i check it Network Enabled it always returns false. I tested the demo from android hive and it has the same result. So network works for you from 4.4 onwards?

Comment: Yes i am getting GPS value and Network value as well .  try to change the sim card provider,and switch off your mobile and on it and try. ensure GPS has switched on . and check the LOG cat value for lat and long

Comment: If GPS is on then it returns latitude and longitude. Without GPS it doesnt return anything. Will try with different SIM.

Comment: I have seen issue with two different device and different SIM. Are you getting values with GPS OFF?

Comment: if GPS is OFF you wont get the GPS lat and long

Comment: It was because your device was not storing a last known location. just try  Go to Google Maps and pinpointed my location with GPS, then a value was returned for getLastKnownLocation()

Comment: When i turn on GPS, went into map and it showed location and then turned OFF GPS, went again into my own app and it showed location but after few minutes it started to show 0.0

Comment: why you are turning off the GPS??? it must be on. then try to get lastknownlocaiton from your code it should work

Comment: We have to get location with GPS OFF. We are fetching location every 15 minutes throughout the day so cant afford to keep GPS ON. Do you see any other alternative?

Comment: No you cant . if GPS is off you can not able to get the exact location.

Comment: But with GPS OFF, we can get location below 4.4. So it got changed from 4.4 onwards?

Comment: if GPS is off you can not get the GPS location you can get network location. in any version of android . but the network location is not exact location. it will take the lat and long from network provider .

Comment: can we get network location in 5.0 that was the question? I am not getting it

Comment: you can get it check properly with logcat and let me know what value you are getting. if you want the network value alone then remove the GPS code in service class and check with logcat and let me know

Comment: You may want to listen to NETWORK_PROVIDER as well which in absent of the GPS location it estimates the location coming from cell towers and WiFi spots.

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);

Furthermore to get a quick geographic location check out the Application.getLastKnownLocation() method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73146/discussion-between-droid-dev-and-john).

Comment: I don't get the solution but unfortunately have to award bounty to you. If you get the solution please post it here. Cheers!!

Comment: sure i will for your problem if i get the solution i will update you . Thanks @droid_dev

Answer (score 2):

When you call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` this tells Android that you would like to be called back when the user's location changes. If you don't have GPS enabled and you want to use NETWORK_PROVIDER, you need to have Internet access. This all happens asynchronously. You call `requestLocationUpdates()` and then some time later, Android will call you back by calling `onLocationChanged()` with the new location.

What you are doing after calling `requestLocationUpdates()` is immediately calling `getLastKnownLocation()` which may or may not return something useful. In your implementation of `onLocationChanged()` you are doing nothing. You will need to wait until Android calls `onLocationChanged()` at which point you should store the passed `Location` parameter in your member variable.

Comment: `isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` It always returns false from `4.4` onwards

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone? Is network location enabled in the settings? This all sounds kinda wierd.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: MOTO G & LG G2 device

Comment: Any idea about the issue?

Comment: No, sorry. no clue. If `isProviderEnabled()` is returning false then there is something wrong with the way the device is set up. Perhaps you've accidentally disabled network location?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `FusedLocationApi` would be a better solution see https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: As per `android hive` example its using `FusedLocationApi` and its not working too