# I cant get latitude and longitude in lollipop.It works fine in other versions and maximum sdk is 22

Tags: android, location, android-permissions

I cant get latitude and longitude in lollipop.It works fine in other versions like gingerbread and kitkat and maximum sdk is 22. I have given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.project2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Java code .

```
package com.example.project2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.util.Log;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
 // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
 private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 1 meters
 // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10 * 1; // 10 sec
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected Context context;
protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;
TextView txtLat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);

locationManager =  (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.Location_Service);          
// getting GPS status
gps_enabled = locationManager
.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// getting network status
 network_enabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVID   ER);

if (gps_enabled) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
} else if (network_enabled) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
};
} 

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
   txtLat.setText("Latitude:"+ location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:"
    + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){                
    Log.d("Latitude", "status");
   }
   }
```

I did it in Eclipse Juno.My main intention is to get location and send to another mobile which i provided.But first I am not getting any location.

Comment: Are you experiencing any force close or it just returns 0 0 for lat and longitude... ??

Comment: Put here the code that you used to get latitude and longitude.

Comment: Check that in Lollipop device  Google play service lib is installed or not?

Comment: dude with this piece of code no one will be able to help u....

Comment: No i didn't get any force close error @Gowtham Raj

Comment: Yes it was installed and updated @Blue Green

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following links.

[Location issue with lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885759/location-returns-0-0-with-wifi-3g-4g-in-lollipop-5-0-2)

[Retrieve current location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

It may help you. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using this old method and look at [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)